# Read a single sub-entry from the authenticated user

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

I'm using the "*Viewer pattern*" to fetch images that belong to the authenticated user:

```json
type Query {
  me: User! @auth
}

type User {
  name: String!
  images: [Image] @hasMany
}
```

And I fetch with:

```json
{
  me {
    images {
      id
      url
    }
  }
}
```

This all works well, but it returns me all the images from the user.

My question is: **How to get a single image from the authenticated user by its ID?**

I tried this:

```json
type User {
  name: String!
  images: [Image] @hasMany

  "Fetch image by its ID"
  image(id: ID @eq): Image @find
}
```

And I fetch with:

```json
{
  me {
    image(id: 4) {
      id
      url
    }
  }
}
```

While this works, it creates a **huge security** issue. Anyone logged in can access any image from any user.

I tried to mix `@find` and `@whereAuth` but I got this

exception:

```
Call to a member function getRelationExistenceQuery() on null
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong. The `@whereAuth` needs a parameter:

```json
type User {
  name: String!
  images: [Image] @hasMany

  "Fetch image by its ID"
  image(id: ID @eq): Image @find @whereAuth(relation: "user")
}
```

Alternatively, you can replace `@find` with `@where` + `@first`:

```json
type User {
  name: String!
  images: [Image] @hasMany

  "Fetch image by its ID"
  image(id: ID @where): Image @whereAuth(relation: "user") @first
}
```

And of course, there's always the alternative of using Policies.